# BigQuery and GCM

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create an Android app that extracts information from a table in BigQuery. In order to do this, do I have to have to implement Google Cloud Messaging? If so, do I have to have a GCM server? Is there a way, the app can authenticate directly with BigQuery and fire a query?

Comment: Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I can't seem to find any guides on whether this is possible and how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make calls to BigQuery, you shouldn't need anything like Google Cloud Messaging (I'm not actually sure what that is). 
You can either use the BigQuery java client (info [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/gettingstartedwithjava)) or you can make raw http requests to BigQuery (you'll need to use Oauth2 for authorization).

You also might consider using an appengine app to proxy the requests to bigquery. That can make auth easier, so you don't need your BigQuery credentials in the android app.

Comment: So I already have a (desktop) java program. I'm trying to build an android app that can authenticate a user and run queries on Bigquery. For example, I am trying to develop an app that will run on my phone to query the employee database by clicking a button. Is this possible? 

Using the java client you've linked to would require me to bundle all the library files into the APK, right? Is that the only way I could do this? 


I want to avoid a proxy app if possible. I want users to have direct read-only access to the database via an android app.

Comment: Authentication might be a problem - you probably don't want users running arbitrary queries? How about proxying queries through an App Engine app?

Comment: I am authenticating user's using the Account Manager - i.e. only users with a valid account will be able to access it.

The reason why I want to avoid proxy is to avoid a server and maintenance headaches that might arise from it.

It might help if I gave a little more insight - using the employee example: I am writing an app that only employees of a certain domain can use. Once authenticated, they can - say enter a valid colleague's email id in a search field and the app will fire the query on BigQuery and get the colleague's details. Not giving the user direct access to run random queries.

Comment: Any one? I've tried a lot of different forums to find an answer for this to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same.
I am able to do it in the Xamarin Studio(which uses C# API library of Google APIs).
Well..
First of all you need to authenticate the user..
The authentication is done using

```
private readonly static Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticator Auth = new       Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticator (clientId,new Uri ("https://www.example.com/oauth2callback"),   Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.BigqueryService.Scopes.Bigquery.GetStringValue ());

        Intent authIntent = Auth.GetUI (v.Context);  
        StartActivityForResult (authIntent, 1);//This will open and ask for Google account
```

So Auth is the Authorisation object.

```
            var Service = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.BigqueryService (Auth); //Creates the BigQuery Service


            string query = "SELECT year, SUM(record_weight) as births FROM publicdata:samples.natality GROUP BY year";

            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.JobsResource j = Service.Jobs;
            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.QueryRequest qr = new Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.QueryRequest ();

            qr.Query = query;
            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.QueryResponse response = j.Query (qr, projectId).Fetch ();

            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableRow row = response.Rows.FirstOrDefault ();
            Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableCell cell = row.F.FirstOrDefault ();
```

The above code is with respect Google APIs .NET library.
I am trying to use the Java API library.
I'll update my answer as soon as I am successful.

Hope the above answer gives you a starting point or an idea till then. :)